# total sales of each product in magento

Tags: magento

How to get the total sales of each product in magento?

Comment: Mind to show some code you've tried?

Comment: Sold to a user, sold for a store, sold for the entire system?  It's not clear what you're trying to fetch.

Comment: i want to fetch total sales of each product.

Comment: and also want to get purchased product by customer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alan pointed out there's a number of different ways to qualify sales for a product.

But to get you started an easy way is to use the reporting module.

```
/** @var Mage_Report_Model_Mysql4_Product_Sold_Collection **/
$report = Mage::getResourceModel('report/product_sold_collection');
```

You can set a date range or other criteria if you want. Once you have your collection just iterate over it, something like this:

```
foreach ($report AS $product) {
    echo $product->getOrderedQty();
}
```

There are other ways to do this too, but this should be a starting point.