# Magento, Where is getOrderedQty() Function?

Tags: magento

Hello I have trying to learn Magento, So would be appreciated if anyone helps.

I saw people initiate class

```
Mage::getResouceModel('report/product_sold_collection');
```

Then they iterate over the collection using foreach loop and use

```
getOrderedQty() method.
```

Like in this thread.
[total sales of each product in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764361/total-sales-of-each-product-in-magento)

Where is this method defined? In which class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method doesn't exist.  All Magento Objects (that is, objects which inherit from `Varien_Object`) allow you to `get` and `set` data properties.

```
$object->setData('the_thing',$value);
echo $object->getData('the_thing')
```

**On top** of this, there's also special setter and getter methods implemented with PHP's "magic methods".  That is, you can get/set a data property by camel casing it's name, and calling it like this

```
$object->setMyThing($value);
echo $object->getMyThing();
```

I searched the Magento codebase, and there's no definition for a "`getOrderedQty`" method.  That means it's one of the above mentioned magic methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Alan, So you mean to say there is some column in the database named OrderedQty ?

Comment: 1. It would be names ordered_qty  2. It's not necessarily an database column.  Reports draw their data from many different locations, and it may be something that's calculated and set.